# Changing the Precision of a Float and Storing in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I have searched around for an answer to this and only found pieces of my problem.
I commented the code through the process to say what works and what doesnt and
what errors I get for each line. Thanks in advance.

```
        #
        # list_of_numbers is a list with numbers
        # like '3.543345354'
        #
        # I want to change to a number with two places 
        #
        #
        # for each item in the list
        for idx, value in enumerate(list_of_numbers):
            # make sure it is not none 
            if value != None: 
                #
                # convert to a float - this works
                temp_val = float(value)
                # test and print the format - yep this works
                print("%.2f" % temp_val)
                # store in a new variable - works
                formatted_number = "%.2f" % temp_val
                # check - yep looks good so far. the line blow will print 3.54 etc
                print formatted_number
                #
                # now try to store it back
                # 
                # the below two lines when I try both give me the 
                #  unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'error
                list_of_numbers[idx] = formatted_number
                list_of_numbers[idx] = '%s' % formatted_number
                #
                # the line below give me the error
                # float argument required, not str 
                list_of_numbers[idx] = '%f' % formatted_number
                #
                # so from the above error formatted_number is a string. 
                # so why cant I set the variable with the string
                #
                # the ONLY thing that works is the lone below but I 
                # dont want an integer
                #
                list_of_numbers[idx] = int(float(value ))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `round` function:

```
n2 = round(n, 2)
```

Also, be forewarned: floats are imprecise, and when you round to two places, then print them, they may look like they have more.  You will need to use `%.2f` in your format string to display them with two places.  If you need absolute precision (say for money), `Decimal` may be better for you.

Comment: Thanks! I had looked at the round function and saw a few horror stories about using it. I will give it a shot. Although I still am wondering why the value would not update in the array.

Comment: To be honest, most of the errors you mention in the comments in that code don't make any sense.  I suspect they are not from the lines you show, but from further on in your program.